# android google maps button on popup

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Okay. What I have so far is an Android app with a Google map on which I've placed a bunch of icons that, when clicked on, create a popup with some text on it. Is there any way to place a button on that popup? If this is not possible, is there some way to make a button appear when an icon on Google Maps is selected?

In case you're wondering, the code I'm using now looks like this.

```
itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(new OverlayItem(point, title, text));
//actually a whole bunch of OverlayItems, each with their own location and text
//but this is the general shape of it.
mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);
```

---

**Edit:**

There are different kinds of popups used with different versions (check yourself in the emulator versions) of the GoogleMaps app. The first popup simple displays the title of the location (Android 2.3.3).

[image: GoogleMaps popup]

The second popup shows the title and arrow indicator. (Android 4.0.3)

[image: GoogleMaps popup with arrow]

Interesting enough: I noticed that both popups are **clickable** and start another activity that shows details about the location.

Answer (score 1):

The `mapviewballon` project https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons/ allows you to use your own custom layout for these popup.

I did not test with buttons on it but I do not see why I would not work.

The example projects shows the following types of popup balloons.

[image: Popup balloon with arrow]

[image: Popup balloon with picutre]

[image: Popup balloon with X]

Answer (score 0):

Here is [another project](http://crazyandroidian.blogspot.de/2011/10/custom-mapview-popup-in-android.html) that creates a custom popup balloon. The project can be downloaded at the end of the article.

[image: Popup balloon]