# how to show address in google map when click any point ?

Tags: android, google-maps, popup

how do i show pop up message in map application like this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1FwQ.jpg

i made a gogle map application but is not show any address this is my code how do i show address message of any point when click on that location like in this image??

```
 import java.util.List;

import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
 import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;
import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;

public class AndroidGoogleMapsActivity extends MapActivity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Displaying Zooming controls
    MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    /**
     * Changing Map Type
     * */
    // mapView.setSatellite(true); // Satellite View
    // mapView.setStreetView(true); // Street View
    // mapView.setTraffic(true); // Traffic view

    /**
     * showing location by Latitude and Longitude
     * */        
    MapController mc = mapView.getController();
    double lat = Double.parseDouble("48.85827758964043");
    double lon = Double.parseDouble("2.294543981552124");
    GeoPoint geoPoint = new GeoPoint((int)(lat * 1E6), (int)(lon * 1E6));
    mc.animateTo(geoPoint);
    mc.setZoom(15);
    mapView.invalidate(); 


    /**
     * Placing Marker
     * */
    List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
    Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.mark_red);
    AddItemizedOverlay itemizedOverlay = 
         new AddItemizedOverlay(drawable, this);


    OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(geoPoint, "Hello", "Sample Overlay  
  item");

    itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
    mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);

}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    return false;
}
 }


         import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;

public class AddItemizedOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> {

   private ArrayList<OverlayItem> mapOverlays = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();

   private Context context;

   public AddItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker) {
        super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
   }

   public AddItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, Context context) {
        this(defaultMarker);
        this.context = context;
   }

   @Override
   protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
      return mapOverlays.get(i);
   }

   @Override
   public int size() {
      return mapOverlays.size();
   }

   @Override
   protected boolean onTap(int index) {
      Log.e("Tap", "Tap Performed");
      return true;
   }

   public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay) {
      mapOverlays.add(overlay);
       this.populate();
   }

   /**
    * Getting Latitude and Longitude on Touch event
    * **/
   @Override
   public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event, MapView mapView) 
   {   

       if (event.getAction() == 1) {                
           GeoPoint geopoint = mapView.getProjection().fromPixels(
               (int) event.getX(),
               (int) event.getY());
           // latitude
           double lat = geopoint.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6;
           // longitude
           double lon = geopoint.getLongitudeE6() / 1E6;
           Toast.makeText(context, "Lat: " + lat + ", Lon: "+lon,    
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }                            
       return false;
   } 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.pocketjourney.view;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.hws.AmpleHarvest.MoreInformation;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Paint.Style;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.graphics.RectF;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;
import com.hws.AmpleHarvest.AmpleHarvestActivity;
import com.hws.AmpleHarvest.PantryLocation;
import com.hws.AmpleHarvest.R;


public class MapLocationOverlay  extends Overlay  {

    private boolean isNameAddHold=true;

     private Bitmap bitmap,bitCross,bitMoreInformation;
    int testX,testY,count=0;
    int infoWindowOffsetX,infoWindowOffsetY;
    public String name,address,argName,argAddress,argid;
    //  Store these as global instances so we don't keep reloading every time
    private Bitmap bubbleIcon, shadowIcon;

    private MapLocationViewer mapLocationViewer;
    double toLat, toLng;

    private Paint   innerPaint, borderPaint, textPaint;
    private boolean isRemovePriorPopup=false;
    private boolean temp=true,first=true, firstDraw = true;
    public boolean tempDefaule=true;
    public MoreInformation myMoreInformation;
    public PantryLocation location;

    //  The currently selected Map Location...if any is selected.  This tracks whether an information  
    //  window should be displayed & where...i.e. whether a user 'clicked' on a known map location
    private PantryLocation selectedMapLocation;  

    public MapLocationOverlay(MapLocationViewer mapLocationViewer,PantryLocation arglocation) {

        this.mapLocationViewer = mapLocationViewer;
        location=arglocation;
        bubbleIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mapLocationViewer.getResources(),R.drawable.bubble);
        shadowIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mapLocationViewer.getResources(),R.drawable.shadow);
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mapLocationViewer.getResources(),R.drawable.infowindow);
        bitCross = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mapLocationViewer.getResources(),R.drawable.crass);
        bitMoreInformation = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mapLocationViewer.getResources(),R.drawable.more_informations_new
                );

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e, MapView mapView) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         if (e.getAction() == 0)
         {
             this.tempDefaule=false;
         }
         if (e.getAction() == 1)
         {
             this.tempDefaule=false;
         }
         if (e.getAction() == 2)
         {
             this.tempDefaule=false;
         }
        return super.onTouchEvent(e, mapView);

    }







    @Override
    public boolean onTap(GeoPoint p, MapView    mapView)  {
        //this.tempDefaule=false;
        //  Store whether prior popup was displayed so we can call invalidate() & remove it if necessary.

        //  Next test whether a new popup should be displayed

            selectedMapLocation = getHitMapLocation(mapView,p);


            mapView.invalidate();

//      if (selectedMapLocation != null || isRemovePriorPopup==true) {
//          
//          mapView.invalidate();
//      }       

        //  Lastly return true if we handled this onTap()
        return selectedMapLocation != null;
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow) {

        drawMapLocations(canvas, mapView, shadow);
        //this.tempDefaule=false;
        drawInfoWindow(canvas, mapView, shadow);
        //this.tempDefaule=false;
        }

    /**
     * Test whether an information balloon should be displayed or a prior balloon hidden.
     */
    private PantryLocation getHitMapLocation(MapView    mapView, GeoPoint   tapPoint) {

        //  Track which MapLocation was hit...if any
        PantryLocation hitMapLocation = null;

        RectF hitTestRecr = new RectF();
        Point screenCoords = new Point();
        ArrayList<PantryLocation> iterator =mapLocationViewer.getMapLocations();
        for(int i=0;i<iterator.size();i++) {       
            PantryLocation testLocation = iterator.get(i);

            //  Translate the MapLocation's lat/long coordinates to screen coordinates
            mapView.getProjection().toPixels(testLocation.getPoint(), screenCoords);

            // Create a 'hit' testing Rectangle w/size and coordinates of our icon
            // Set the 'hit' testing Rectangle with the size and coordinates of our on screen icon
            hitTestRecr.set(-bubbleIcon.getWidth()/2,-bubbleIcon.getHeight(),bubbleIcon.getWidth()/2,0);
            hitTestRecr.offset(screenCoords.x,screenCoords.y);

            //  Finally test for a match between our 'hit' Rectangle and the location clicked by the user
            mapView.getProjection().toPixels(tapPoint, screenCoords);
            //hitMapLocation = testLocation;
            if (hitTestRecr.contains(screenCoords.x,screenCoords.y)) {
                hitMapLocation = testLocation;
                first = true;
                isNameAddHold = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        testX=(int)screenCoords.x;
        testY=(int)screenCoords.y;
        //  Lastly clear the newMouseSelection as it has now been processed
        tapPoint = null;
        if(hitMapLocation==null && selectedMapLocation!=null)
        return selectedMapLocation; 

        return hitMapLocation;

    }

    private void drawMapLocations(Canvas canvas, MapView    mapView, boolean shadow) {
        int i=0;count++;
        ArrayList<PantryLocation> iterator =mapLocationViewer.getMapLocations();
        Point screenCoords = new Point();
        for(i=0;i<iterator.size();i++) {       
            PantryLocation location = iterator.get(i);
            mapView.getProjection().toPixels(location.getPoint(), screenCoords);
            //mapView.getController().setCenter(location.getPoint());
            if (shadow) {
                //  Only offset the shadow in the y-axis as the shadow is angled so the base is at x=0; 
                canvas.drawBitmap(shadowIcon, screenCoords.x, screenCoords.y - shadowIcon.getHeight(),null);
            } else {
                canvas.drawBitmap(bubbleIcon, screenCoords.x - bubbleIcon.getWidth()/2, screenCoords.y - bubbleIcon.getHeight(),null);
            }

        }
//      if(i==iterator.size()){
//          this.tempDefaule=false;}
if(tempDefaule==true)
{

            PantryLocation location1 = this.location;
            //mapView.getProjection().toPixels(location.getPoint(), screenCoords);
            Point screenCoord = new Point();
            mapView.getController().setCenter(location1.getPoint());
            mapView.getController().setZoom(15);
        //  tempDefaule=false;
                //mapView.getController().setCenter(location.getPoint());   

        }

            //tempDefaule=false;    
}           //mapView.getProjection().toPixels(location.getPoint(), screenCoord);
            //canvas.drawBitmap(bubbleIcon, screenCoord.x - bubbleIcon.getWidth()/2, screenCoord.y - bubbleIcon.getHeight(),null);
            //mapView.invalidate();


    private void drawInfoWindow(Canvas canvas, MapView  mapView, boolean shadow) {
        //this.tempDefaule=false;
        if ( selectedMapLocation != null) {
            if ( shadow) {
                //  Skip painting a shadow in this tutorial
            } else {
                //  First determine the screen coordinates of the selected MapLocation
                isRemovePriorPopup=true;
                Point selDestinationOffset = new Point();

//              if(first){
//                  //mapView.getController().setCenter(selectedMapLocation.getPoint());
//                  first = false;
//                  //mapView.getController().setZoom(15);
//              }
                mapView.getProjection().toPixels(selectedMapLocation.getPoint(), selDestinationOffset);

                //  Setup the info window with the right size & location
                int INFO_WINDOW_WIDTH = 125;
                int INFO_WINDOW_HEIGHT = 25;
                RectF infoWindowRect = new RectF(0,0,100,20);   
                RectF closeRect = new RectF(0,0,20,20); 
                 infoWindowOffsetX = selDestinationOffset.x-INFO_WINDOW_WIDTH/2;
                 infoWindowOffsetY = selDestinationOffset.y-INFO_WINDOW_HEIGHT-bubbleIcon.getHeight();
                 infoWindowRect.offset(infoWindowOffsetX+95,infoWindowOffsetY-45);
                 closeRect.offset(infoWindowOffsetX+160,infoWindowOffsetY-90);
//
//               int TEXT_OFFSET_X = 10;
//                  int TEXT_OFFSET_Y = 15;
//                  
                 Paint myPaintBlack=new Paint();
                    Paint myPaintWhite=new Paint();

                    myPaintWhite.setARGB(255, 255, 255, 255);


                //  Draw inner info window
                canvas.drawRoundRect(infoWindowRect, 5, 5, getInnerPaint());

                //  Draw border for info window
                canvas.drawRoundRect(infoWindowRect, 5, 5, getBorderPaint());

                //  Draw the MapLocation's name


                myPaintBlack.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                myPaintBlack.setTextSize(20);

//              canvas.drawText(selectedMapLocation.getAddress(),infoWindowOffsetX+TEXT_OFFSET_X,infoWindowOffsetY+TEXT_OFFSET_Y,getTextPaint());
                canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, infoWindowOffsetX-50, infoWindowOffsetY-100,getInnerPaint());
                //canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap1, infoWindowOffsetX-45, infoWindowOffsetY-80,getInnerPaint());
                if(isNameAddHold)
                {
                argid=selectedMapLocation.getID();
                argName=selectedMapLocation.getName();
                name=selectedMapLocation.getName();
                toLat = selectedMapLocation.getLatitude();
                toLng = selectedMapLocation.getLongitude();
                if(name.length()>18)
                name=selectedMapLocation.getName().substring(0,18)+"..";
                argAddress=selectedMapLocation.getAddress();
                address=selectedMapLocation.getAddress();
                if(address.length()>30)
                address=selectedMapLocation.getAddress().substring(0,30)+"..";
                }
                canvas.drawText(name,infoWindowOffsetX-45,infoWindowOffsetY-70,myPaintBlack);
                myPaintBlack.setTextSize(13);
                canvas.drawText(address,infoWindowOffsetX-45,infoWindowOffsetY-55,myPaintBlack);

            //  Draw inner info window
                canvas.drawRoundRect(infoWindowRect, 5, 5, getInnerPaint());

                //  Draw border for info window
                canvas.drawRoundRect(infoWindowRect, 5, 5, getBorderPaint());

                //CloseRect
//              canvas.drawRoundRect(closeRect, 5, 5, getInnerPaint());
//              canvas.drawRoundRect(closeRect, 5, 5, getBorderPaint());

                //  Draw the MapLocation's name
                myPaintBlack.setColor(Color.CYAN);
                myPaintBlack.setTextSize(11);
                //canvas.drawText("Click for more info..",infoWindowOffsetX+105,infoWindowOffsetY-33,myPaintBlack);
                canvas.drawBitmap(bitMoreInformation, infoWindowOffsetX+95, infoWindowOffsetY-45,getInnerPaint());
                //canvas.drawBitmap(bitCross, infoWindowOffsetX+160, infoWindowOffsetY-90,getInnerPaint());

            }
        }
        if(isRemovePriorPopup)
        {
        if(((testX>(infoWindowOffsetX+95)&&testX<(infoWindowOffsetX+195)))&&(testY>(infoWindowOffsetY-45)&&testY<(infoWindowOffsetY-25)))
            {
            if(temp){
                try
                {
                    temp=false;
                    isNameAddHold=false;
                isRemovePriorPopup=false;
                Context context=mapLocationViewer.cn;
                Toast.makeText(context, "Loading...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent=new Intent(context, MoreInformation.class);
                intent.putExtra("Id",argid);
                intent.putExtra("Name",argName);
                intent.putExtra("Address",argAddress);
                intent.putExtra("Latitude",toLat);
                intent.putExtra("Longitude",toLng);

                context.startActivity(intent);

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Log.d("Redirected Error :", ex.getMessage());
                }
        //canvas.drawText("This is for Testing",testX,testY,myPaintBlack);
            }}
            else if(((testX>(infoWindowOffsetX+160)&&testX<(infoWindowOffsetX+180)))&&(testY>(infoWindowOffsetY-90)&&testY<(infoWindowOffsetY-70)))
            {

                if(isRemovePriorPopup)
                {
                 isRemovePriorPopup=false;                  
                 selectedMapLocation=null;
                 draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);
                // mapLocationViewer.setDZoom();
                }

            }
        }
    }

    public Paint getInnerPaint() {
        if ( innerPaint == null) {
            innerPaint = new Paint();
            innerPaint.setARGB(225, 75, 75, 75); //gray
            innerPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        }
        return innerPaint;
    }

    public Paint getBorderPaint() {
        if ( borderPaint == null) {
            borderPaint = new Paint();
            borderPaint.setARGB(255, 255, 255, 255);
            borderPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
            borderPaint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
            borderPaint.setStrokeWidth(2);
        }
        return borderPaint;
    }

    public Paint getTextPaint() {
        if ( textPaint == null) {
            textPaint = new Paint();
            textPaint.setARGB(255, 255, 255, 255);
            textPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        }
        return textPaint;
    }


}
```

Comment: @HayyaAnam i'm use this and it is work for me. if that not what u want that mean i'm not understand your question correct.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11108847/android-google-maps-button-on-popup

Comment: or u can build an customdialogue
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3728990/how-to-create-a-completely-custom-dialogue-popup-in-android-change-overlay-colo

Comment: @HayyaAnam still have a problem ??