# Show Current Address Location as Textview

Tags: java, android, mobile

I am building an app that grabs user's address depending on the current location of the user. I want the user to be able to see it like a textView(In a Moving Marqueee) format. Please help
To cut it short:
What I need is a textview that would display user's live location and the time at which the user's was at a particular location. It should show the address and time in textview format.. Please also include the location code.

Below is My XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.pyjel.whatsmyusername">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/abeezee"
        android:text="what's my username?"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.273" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/abeezee"
        android:text='"a code would be sent to your phone number, enter code to continue"'
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.509"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.715" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/signupEmailAddress"
        android:layout_width="306dp"
        android:layout_height="26dp"

        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="44dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="268dp"
        android:background="@drawable/edittexttintcolor"
        android:backgroundTint="@drawable/edittexttintcolor"
        android:fontFamily="@font/abeezee"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="phone"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:textColorHint="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"

        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    <requestFocus />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/abeezee"
        android:text='"to retrieve username, you will have to verify the phone number used during registration"'
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.358" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/retrieveUsername"
        android:layout_width="105dp"
        android:layout_height="43dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="432dp"
        android:background="@drawable/buttonbackgroundcolor"
        android:fontFamily="@font/abeezee"
        android:onClick="retrieve"
        android:text="retrieve"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.501"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.488" />








</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And Below is My Java class

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class whatsmyusername extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView( R.layout.activity_whatsmyusername );
    }
}
```

I want it to look like the below image, and also please it should have the time at which the user is at a particular location...I know my question is a bit lengthy, but please I need help on  this.[This is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6UnvK.png)

Comment: Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11108847/android-google-maps-button-on-popup

Comment: I am not talking about maps, I only needed the function whereby live locations are updated in Text form...not in map form...

Answer (score 0):

To get the address using location co-ordinates. i.e latitudes and longitudes, Android Locations provides a lookup API, You can find the official document here https://developer.android.com/training/location/display-address.html

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, i am looking forward to more